# MySQL: Cannot add or update a child row

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1452

I am fairly new to MySQl and wanted to connect two tables with a keys when I got this error. I browsed through some of the related questions but I cannot seem to find what is wrong.

First I created this table and it works:

```
CREATE TABLE uniquepeps (ID INT NOT NULL, Sequence CHAR(30) 
NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (Sequence));
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "D://...//Uniquepeps.txt" INTO TABLE uniquepeps;
```

The table looks like this and works:

```
1   AAAATTTTTGGGGGG
2   GGGGGUUUUUKKK
3   OOOOPPPPMMMNN
```

Then I created the other table:

```
CREATE TABLE peps (ID INT NOT NULL, Sequencepeps CHAR(30) 
NOT NULL, PROTID INT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID), CONSTRAINT 
Seq_fk FOREIGN KEY (Sequencepeps) references uniquepeps(Sequence));
```

But when I tried to load in the data it didn't work and I got an error

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "D://...//Pepsandprots.txt" INTO TABLE peps; 
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`biology`.`peps`, CONSTRAINT `Seq_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`Sequencepeps`) REFERENCES `uniquepeps` (`Sequence`) )
```

The data for the second table is:

```
1       AAAATTTTTGGGGGG 1
2       AAAATTTTTGGGGGG 2
3       AAAATTTTTGGGGGG 3
4       AAAATTTTTGGGGGG 4
5       GGGGGUUUUUKKK   1
6       GGGGGUUUUUKKK   8
7       OOOOPPPPMMMNN   9
8       OOOOPPPPMMMNN   25
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The error means, that you are trying to insert a value into `Sequencepeps` in the table `peps` which desn't exist in the table `uniquepeps` in the column `Sequence`.

Looking closer, you can see that there is probably a problem with your input file, in the `uniquepeps` you have written `GGGGGUUUUUKKK` however in the `peps`-file you have two different similar ones: `GGGGGUUUUUKKK` (which is correct) and `GGGGUUUUUKKK` (which is missing a `G`) - maybe it is a typo from your side?

Comment: Yes, it was a typo in the question. I edited now but in my file I want to load in the sequence was correct and the error remains

Comment: ok, I see - and you are sure that all the `peps` exist in `uniquepeps`? Is the content description in your question the whole file, or just the beginning?

Comment: Yes, it is the whole file. I tried something before (on 2 different files) where my keys where just ID's and it worked. I wanted to see if I could use sequences as a key as well. I am only aware of the true basics but could it be something technical? I read somethings about engines but have no idea how it works or what it is. Thank you already for looking into this!

Comment: I don't know why but if I add a column Unique_peps_ID in pepsandprots and use this as foreign key to the primary key ID in uniquepeps, I have no error and I can load in the data without a problem. I guess I can work around it but I don't understand why the previous did not work.